# Money in checked luggage

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, money, airport-security

I accidentaly left money in my checked baggage flying from Germany to Brazil. It is something like 400 Euro. I realized this only as I was already flying. How often is the baggage 
X ray scanned? Is there a chance it will be OK?

Comment: What specifically is your concern? That the money is stolen, or that you have problems with customs?

Comment: Since it is not a very large amount, my concern is that it can be stolen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people working in airports are honest, will not steal.
So there is a very good chance that the money will come through, even when the case is checked by X-ray or by hand.
Even more likely as the most likely location for checking by X-ray is in Germany. And German border control and security forces are not known for stealing.

I would not put money in checked baggage on purpose but as your baggage is on its way and you can not do anything about it you can better keep your mind on what you can influence.

Comment: You are right. There is nothing I can do now. I just wanted to hear from more ecperienced people. Oi am glad the baggage is most likely scanned in Germany and probably not in Brazil

Comment: @Sam P. Arons Was your case securely locked? It’s possible bags are scanned both at the departure and arrival airport https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130009/do-airports-x-ray-checked-in-baggage-on-arrival If you’re more worried about the arrival airport, I would check it for signs of tampering / open it to see whether your money is still there before you leave the baggage collection area

Comment: Which could inform the OP that his case was opened, but will not tell him by whom. In any event, the airline will energetically resist any claim for cash that the OP says was in the case.

Comment: @David Indeed. But should the worst happen, and especially if the OP has insurance that might cover the loss, the OP will need to file a report with the airline and the police, which they could do before leaving the airport.

Comment: Thanks you all for the comments. The trip is now over and I must say that everything is fine. No tampering whatsoever and the money was there. Perhaps I was lucky, I do not know. I will not try again and I do not recommend that anyone do.